# Extract file name from path in awk program

Tags: awk, filenames

I have an awk script and I have passed a CSV file to it.

```
awk -f script.awk /home/abc/imp/asgd.csv
```

What am I doing is to get FILENAME within `script.awk`. FILENAME gives me the whole path. As I am in awk I cannot use `basename FILENAME`.

```
print FILENAME;
/home/abc/imp/asgd.csv
```

I have tried with this within `script.awk`

```
echo $FILENAME | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
```

but I cannot execute this within `script.awk`. How can I get `asgd.csv` within an awk program?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Several options:

```
awk '
  function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }
  {print FILENAME, basename(FILENAME)}' /path/to/file
```

Or:

```
awk '
  function basename(file, a, n) {
    n = split(file, a, "/")
    return a[n]
  }
  {print FILENAME, basename(FILENAME)}' /path/to/file
```

Note that those implementations of `basename` should work for the common cases, but not in corner cases like `basename /path/to/x///` where they return the empty string instead of `x` or `/` where they return the empty string instead of `/`, though for regular files, that should not happen.

The first one will not work properly if the file paths (up to the last `/`) contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale (typically this kind of thing happens in UTF-8 locales with filenames encoded in some 8 bit single byte character set). You can work around that by fixing the locale to C where every sequence of byte form valid characters.

Comment: If you need code that will work easily within an existing awk script without introducing a function, you should use: `n = split(FILENAME, a, "/"); basename=a[n];`. Don't use `sub` as that will actually change the `FILENAME` variable (which is a non-issue with the function since awk uses call by value).

Answer (score 11):

Try this awk one-liner,

```
$ awk 'END{ var=FILENAME; split (var,a,/\//); print a[5]}' /home/abc/imp/asgd.csv
asgd.csv
```

Comment: or `awk 'END{ var=FILENAME; n=split (var,a,/\//); print a[n]}' /home/abc/imp/asgd.csv`

Answer (score 9):

On the systems where `basename` command is available, one could use `awk`'s `system()` function or `expression | getline var` structure to call external `basename` command. This can help accounting for corner cases mentioned in [Stephane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134219/85039).

```
$ awk '{cmd=sprintf("basename %s",FILENAME);cmd | getline out; print FILENAME,out; exit}' /etc///passwd
/etc///passwd passwd
```

Comment: This should be top answer. It's much safer to get basename command than to split by slashes and hope that there is no `\/` in the filename

Answer (score 2):

### Use Awk's Split Function

One way to do this is to use the split function. For example:

```
awk '{idx = split(FILENAME, parts, "/"); print parts[idx]; nextfile}' /path/to/file
```

This even works on multiple files. For example:

> ```
> $ awk '{idx = split(FILENAME, parts, "/"); print parts[idx]; nextfile}' \
>       /etc/passwd /etc/group
> passwd
> group
> ```

Answer (score -1):

the best way to export it from input CSV or directly from input file path you can reverse it , then get 1 column and then again reverse it.

```
function getFileFromPath() {
    FileName=$1
    cat $FileName | while read Filename
    do
        echo $Filename| rev | awk -v FS='/' '{print $1}' | rev 
    done
}
```

or simply

```
echo $FileNamePath| rev | awk -v FS='/' '{print $1}' | rev
```