# awk and windows paths backslash escape character

Tags: awk, gawk

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134212/extract-file-name-from-path-in-awk-program) I found a nice way to extract basename from path with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ var="Z:\201708021541\file name with spaces.123"; n=split(var,a,/\//); print a[n]}'
```

but for backslashes it does not work as the characters seem to become escaped, e.g. the output of the above looks:

```
Z:�708021541
            ile name with spaces.123
```

Now, is there any way to get around in awk? The paths are listed in a file and I cannot (do not want) to preprocess all the files to escape `\`, so I wonder is there a way to tell awk "do not escape"?

Comment: Do you need the basename in `awk` or do you use `awk` because `basename` does not understand Windows paths?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to find the filename portion of a Windows pathname containing backslashes...

```
pathname='Z:\201708021541\file name with spaces.123'
filename=$(basename "${pathname//\\//}")

printf '%s\n' "$filename"
```

This will print

```
file name with spaces.123
```

if run in `bash`.

The parameter substitution `${pathname//\\//}` replaces all backslashes with forward slashes in the value of `$pathname`, which means that the standard `basename` utility can work on it.  The `basename` utility does not care that the path starts with `Z:` (it believes that this is the name of a directory).

Alternatively (shorter, and more portable):

```
pathname='Z:\201708021541\file name with spaces.123'
filename=${pathname##*\\}

printf '%s\n' "$filename"
```

Here, `${pathname##*\\}` will remove everything up to the last backslash in `$pathname`. This parameter substitution is standard, whereas the one used in the first variation will only work in certain shells.

---

Using `awk`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$pathname" | awk '{ sub(".*\\\\", "", $0); print }'
```

The four backslashes are two backslashes escaped once each, because reasons.

Using `sed`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$pathname" | sed 's/.*\\//'
```

Both the `awk` and `sed` solutions work exactly the same way. They substitute everything up to (and including) the last backslash with an empty string.