# extract file name from a list of files in a text file

Tags: text-processing

probably simple, but my head hurts.

i have a list of files with their path in a file named `stuff.txt`.  Looks like this:

```
c:\users\none\file1.txt  
c:\users\none\file2.txt  
g:\home\share\make.log
```

how can I simply get the file name output to another file to look like:

```
file1.txt  
file2.txt  
make.log
```

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)

Comment: i didnt think basename works with files though.

Comment: Iterate the lines of the file. Fix the slashes. Then, `basename` it.

Comment: `sed 's-.*\\__'` should do the trick. Double-backslash as escaped backslash.

Comment: Please confirm your pathnames have \ instead of /

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract file name from path in awk program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134212/extract-file-name-from-path-in-awk-program). Just replace the slash by backslashes

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'\' '{ print $NF }' stuff.txt
```

This sets the field separator to `\` and prints the last field from each line

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put IO::Spec::Win32.basename($_);'   stuff.txt

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'put IO::Spec::Win32.basename($_.trim-trailing);'   stuff.txt
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. The code above takes your file paths and treats them as `IO` objects, of which there are four main classes (Unix, Windows, Cygwin, and QNX). Because you have Windows paths, the `IO::Spec::Win32` method is called (to correctly understand the path delimiter). Finally `basename` gives you the file name. There seems to be some whitespace at the end of the lines, which can be cleaned up with `trim` or `trim-trailing`.

Sample Input:

```
c:\users\none\file1.txt  
c:\users\none\file2.txt  
g:\home\share\make.log
```

Sample Output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
make.log
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Spec/Win32
https://docs.raku.org/routine/basename
https://raku.org